# How to charge iPad with one or more USB devices connected?

Tags: ipad, usb, charging

I use my iPad with lightning power cable, to execute live theater lights show through an ArtNet server to DMX dimmers signals in Wi-Fi.

I need to connect two USB devices to it, one keyboard and one USB buttons tables like the [Novation](http://novationmusic.de/launch) to launch a single light scene from keyboard or button USB table, but at the same time I need to continuously charge the iPad because it will work for 10 hours always connected to lights dimmers.

How I can connect two USB devices to the iPad and charge it the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01F7KJDIM/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01F7KJDIM)

It has a USB port and a port for a lightning cable.  Just connect a powered or unpowered hub to the USB A female and attach your instruments to the hub then connect the new Apple powered USB camera kit with everything hooked up, plus the lightning cable to a computer or USB charger.